# How to hide border from empty text object in fast report

Tags: pascalscript, fastreport

How to hide border in text object when its empty. i have used suppress option for repeating value in same column please refer the image [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDIwc.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use
`procedure DBXQuery1FIELD2OnAfterData(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
  if DBXQuery1FIELD2.Text = '' then
    DBXQuery1FIELD2.Frame.Typ := 0
  else
    DBXQuery1FIELD2.Frame.Typ := ftLeft + ftRight + ftTop;
end;`